# Error when generating dictionary from 2 lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax-error, assignment-operator

I have some code that takes a string input,
 translates it to a list of integers using a dictionary
 then  generates a dict from that list and a list of the alphabet
(I would like to use the alphabet list as the key)

```
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','p','q','r',
            's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ','.','-','-',',','!','?']

def gen_dict() :
    key_dict = {'a':'00', 'b':'01', 'c':'02', 'd':'03', 'e':'04', 'f':'05',
                'g':'06', 'h':'07', 'i':'08', 'j':'09', 'k':'10', 'l':'11',
                'm':'12', 'n':'13', 'o':'14', 'p':'15', 'q':'16', 'r':'17',
                's':'18', 't':'19', 'u':'20', 'v':'21', 'w':'22', 'x':'23',
                'y':'24', 'z':'25', ' ':'26', '.':'27', '-':'28', ',':'29',
                '!':'30', '?':'31'}
    print(key_dict)
    p= 0
    key = key.lower()
    for character in key:
        keyint.append(key_dict[message[p]])
        p += 1
    letter-num_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(alphabet,keyint)}
    print(letter-num_dict)  
key = input()
gen_dict()
```

but the program won't even run,
instead it gives the error message:

> letter-num_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(alphabet,keyint)}
>       ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

I couldn't find anything else online getting this error message for similar reasons so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please use the Preview to check if your question looks alright before posting it. (It does not. You need to format your code correctly.)

Comment: Python cannot use variable names with an operator in them: `letter-num_dict` is as invalid as, say, `10` or `a+b`, for a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use hyphens in variable names.

Change `letter-num_dict` to `letter_num_dict` (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Variables cannot have a dash (`-`) as a part of the name, as Python interprets that as the *minus* operator. Change it to an underscore instead: `letter_num_dict`